# How do I use the following reference without it outcommenting the link?

Tags: bibtex, overleaf, urls, comments, percent-sign

I am quite new to overleaf/latex and have run into a problem.
I want to cite a link which containt % and this outcomments the link is there anyway to get around this?

code:

```
    @book{web:KompetenceProfil,
    author = "UVM",
    title = "Undervisningsvejledning for forsøgsfaget teknologiforståelse",
    year = "2018",
    publisher = "2021",
    address = "\newline \url{https://emu.dk/sites/default/files/2019-02/GSK.%20F%C3%A6lles%20M%C3%A5l.%20Tilg%C3%A6ngelig.%20Teknologiforst%C3%A5else.pdf}"
}
```

So at every % it outcomments the link tried to google around but could not google correctly thank you in advance for my stupidity :)

Comment: Note that the `address` field is not for this. Use the `note` field instead and make use you load the `url` or `xurl` packages, when those package are loaded `\url` should be able to handle `%`. Several bibtex styles "provide" a poormans version of `\url` if it is not already defined, but those versions cannot handle `%`

Comment: Additionally, next time please provide a full minimal example such that we know which packages  you are using.

Comment: it depends on your bibliography system, but you could try to input all `%` as `\%`

Comment: Sorry it actually worked even though it was outcommented. I use hyperref is that ok or would you recommend bibtex?

Comment: still remember to load `xurl`, it works better, also with `hyperref`

Comment: Okay will try thanks first time using overleaf for my thesis

Comment: So sorry for noobie mistakes

Comment: Which bibliography style do you employ? Do you use a citation management package such as `cite` or `natbib`? Do you wish to create numeric or authoryear style citation callouts?

Comment: What do you mean with that exactly?

Comment: The bibliography style is indicated in the argument of `\bibliographystyle`. Without such a direct, BibTeX will not operate on any entries in your bib file.

Comment: The field `publisher = "2021",` would appear to indicate thath the publisher's name is "2021". Is this impression correct?

Comment: I use apalike and publisher I just write Acessed xx date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Tom from Overleaf Support here.)

I'm afraid that you fail victim of a glitch in our current (March 2021) syntax highlighting. Percent signs don't start a comment in a bib file, despite our syntax highlighter suggesting they do, sorry for that. It's a limitation of our current editor that we are aware of and are looking to mitigate, but we can't say when this will happen. Apologies for this once more.

To conclude: The percent signs should work just fine in a bib file.